# split string into char array of some size

Tags: c, string

I an new in c programing so I am not understanding to work for the process.

I have a structure defined like following way.

```
struct codons
{
    char amino_acid[20], slc[20], dna_codon[40];
};

struct codons c1 = {"Isoleucine", "I", "ATT, ATC, ATA"};
struct codons c2 = {"Leucine", "L", "CTT, CTC, CTA, CTG, TTA, TTG"};
```

User has to input the string sequence. for example :

```
printf("Enter the sentence: ");
gets(str);
```

if user enters string like :

```
ATTCTGCTTTTA
```

Then I have to convert this string to 3char length strings like

```
ATT, CTG, CTT, etc.
```

and then, I have to check if that this short string of 3 chars present in structure of not.

I dont have any idea how I can convert the string into 3char string length and check.
Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: You need to show *how* the structure is *declared*. Showing how it's initialized is not quite the same thing.

Comment: [Where's your code so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) At least you're able to get the input from the user and store that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like below:

```
char* input_string = ...;

//check if user entered string that could be divided into 3 letters substrings
if (strlen(input_string) % 3 != 0)
  return;

while (*input_string != '\0')
{
   char string_3l[4] = {'\0'};
   strncpy(string_3l, input_string, 3);

   //check if string_3l is part of structure 
   if ((strstr(string_3l, c1.dna_codon) != NULL) || 
               (strstr(string_3l, c2.dna_codon) != NULL))
   {
        //YOU HAVE MATCH!
   }

   input_string += 3;
}
```

Of course you should check in both c1 and c2 structures.

Comment: Sorry, this was needed in very first version. You can ignore this as this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

To get the first 3 characters of a string just allocate a buffer of that size and put there those characters:

```
char substring[4];
strncpy(substring, input, 3);
char substring[3] = '\0';
```

Then use strstr to check if a string "possibilities" contains the substring:

```
if (strstr(possibilities, substring) != NULL)
    // ...
```

(you didn't posted the struct definition as the comment said, so I can't be more accurate on the real name of "possibilities")

If you want to go on, just do some pointer arithmetic and repeat all the procedure:

```
strncpy(substring, input + 3, 3)
// and so on...
```

(lol, I read "condoms")

Comment: :P (for condoms)...bdw tx for ur reply. i wll try it nw

Comment: I think that you should use 'char substring[4];' and add terminating character at the end (eg substring[3] = '\0';)

Comment: @codewarrior: yes, I should, thanks. I forgot about strstr and just considered strNcpy. I'm editing.