# How to split a string into 3 parts in C

Tags: c, string, function, split, string.h

the question is the following: "How do I split a string into 3 parts in C?"

The string is something similar to the following: "Roberta$$$Anna$$$$$$Massimo$$$"

I need to split it exactly after 10 characters (Roberta$$$, Anna$$$$$$, Massimo$$$), and please notice that they aren't separated by a spacebar, so I think I cannot use the strtok function or the library string.h to split them.

Comment: Always 3 parts? Always 10 characters long? Keeping junk characters? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `strncpy`?

Comment: Yes, always 3 parts, always 10 characters long and keeping the "$" characters.
And I've tried the string.h library with the function strtok and strcpy but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: `strncpy(dest[i],str[i],10)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split string into char array of some size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048917/split-string-into-char-array-of-some-size)

Comment: @Maggiorana Then post your code so we can tell you what in your use of strcpy is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
char source[] = "Roberta$$$Anna$$$$$$Massimo$$$";

char part1[11];
char part2[11];
char part3[11];

memmove(part1, &source[ 0], 10);
part1[10] = '\0';
memmove(part2, &source[10], 10);
part2[10] = '\0';
memmove(part3, &source[20], 10);
part3[10] = '\0';
```

You could use `strncpy()` or `memcpy()` instead of `memmove()`.